# How bitcoin wallets connected between

Tags: security, block

I'm thinking, is it dangerous to buy bitcoin, in case if government want to block it?
How bitcoin wallets connected between?
If I'm right - there are support servers, who providing connection between wallets?
At least, when you downloading cold wallet to your computer, it starts the download and syncs blockchain from the servers?
What if some government wants to block the servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stopping the internet would be easier for your government than blocking bitcoin servers IP's.

You have not to download the blockchain to start using bitcoin or receiving bitcoin, download some wallet offline and use it or use blockchian.info since they support tor network so your government will not be able to block it.

Wallets are not connected to each other, simply its just a software doing some math to give you a new address, existing address or creating a new transaction, then they broadcast that transaction to the bitcoin network (blockchain).

Comment: bit bitcoin network must be connected all together ? So, it's must have centralized servers ?

Comment: Yes, there are DNS Seeds, all nodes connect to these seeds to reach each other or even through the nodes you can reach other nodes, for example, you have connected to my node then you ask me to connect you with other nodes and go on. if you want more information please ask a separate about Bitcoin DNS seeds.